# Can I mock a method for an object that's created in a method I'm testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Can_Login_With_Valid_Credentials()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IMembershipRepository> mockRepository = new Mock<IMembershipRepository>();           

        Mock<LoginViewModel> mockModel = new Mock<LoginViewModel>();
        mockModel.Setup(x => x.IsLoggedIn()).Returns(true);            

        AccountController target = new AccountController(mockRepository.Object);

        //Act
        ActionResult result = target.Login(mockModel.Object);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));

    }
```

And ActionResult in the controller

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        string returnUrl = (string)TempData["ReturnUrl"];           

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel(repository, viewModel);

            if (model.IsLoggedIn())
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                else return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "");
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "");
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

I'm having problems with mocking `model.IsLoggedIn()` in the `ActionMethod`, and it is probably because I'm creating a new instance of the viewmodel `LoginViewModel` in that `ActionMethod`. That is why `mockModel.Setup(x => x.IsLoggedIn()).Returns(true);` in the unit test is not caching it because there is a new instance of the class that has that method.

Is there any way i can mock `model.IsLoggedIn()` in the ActionMethod and make it return `true`?

Comment: That's indeed the problem. Is there a specific reason you're creating a new `LoginViewModel` object instead of manipulating the existing one?

Comment: In a word, no. You're trying to mock a concrete implementation. If the dependency is not being injected in, you can't mock it. The instance of `LoginViewModel` that you pass in is not the instance that `IsLoggedIn` is actually called upon, hence the setup not matching.

Comment: As it stands only TypeMock Isolator or Fakes can help you out. With some refactoring you could can easily test this, creating a `protected virtual CreateLoginViewModel` in your controller would allow you to manipulate it through normal mocking tools. Or reuse the model as Jeroen suggests.

Comment: Yep that's what I was think too! I can't mock it without using existing LoginViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no way to avoid creating new instance of LoginViewModel in the action method, then introduce a factory which does that. Avoid at all costs direct creation of any concrete class - that makes unit testing impossible.

If action method creates an object using the factory, then concrete factory is passed as controller's constructor parameter. That requires IoC container and custom controller factory, which is relatively simple to add to the project.

With this solution in place, unit test actually mocks factory so that mocked factory returns mocked LoginViewModel object (in fact: mocked object that implements ILoginViewModel interface). This is the way in which I do it in all MVC projects and it works perfectly for production code, unit tests and integration tests.

Comment: Thanks for the good idea! That's what I'm gonna do from now on as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above and research, the best way to do that would be by using an existing LoginViewModel instead of creating a new instance of it. Here is the re-factored vision of ActionResult that works with Moq.

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel)
    {
        string returnUrl = (string)TempData["ReturnUrl"];           

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (viewModel.IsLoggedIn(repository))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                else return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "");
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "");
            }
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```